# Where to put outside-aggregate validation?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've got a question regarding outside-aggregate validation.

- In our domain partner can place orders that contain certain products (1).
- Once order is placed (2) he can mark it as paid (3) in our system.
- Once order is marked as paid (4) we assign licences to products in external library service (5).
- Once we know licences are assigned (6) we close entire saga.

Here's a small drawing illustrating the process:

[image]

At this moment besides commands, command handlers and events there are two domain classes that are involved in entire process:

Order aggregate containing business logic
Order saga coordinating entire process and assigning licences

Now, there is one invariant that is not modelled in this process yet - before we mark order as paid we have to check if user does not already have particular licence assigned. We get this from library service as well.

Where would you put this validation? Command handler? Wrap Order in some domain service? Pass some validator to Order constructor?

```
class Order
{
    public function __construct(OrderValidator $validator)
    {
        if (!$validator->isValid($this)) {
            throw new \DomainException();
        }

        // else proceed
    }
}

class OrderValidator
{
    private $libraryServiceClient;

    public function isValid(Order $order)
    {
        // check licence using $libraryServiceClient
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a strict validation, you can pass a "service" that does the validation at the aggregate method that execute the MarkPaid command, and check it before change the state

Comment: I think the user should be part of your model since every order has a user that created it. Then the validation can be simple and still in side of the aggregate. 
The user class can just have a method ->isAllowedToMakePayment() or ->hasLicence()

Comment: @MohamedBouallegue sure but licence check is actually part of different bounded context, so it has to be delegated somewhere - my question is how.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem is in step 3 (Mark order as payed). In this step we need a user (let's call it payer) that marks the order as payed. So when creating this payer object (using factory maybe) we need to know if he is allowed to mark an order as payed. In order to get this information a call should be made to the external library.

What I suggest is to have an application service that have `->markOrderAsPayed($orderId, $payerUserId)`
This method will make a call to 2 domain services. One for getting the payer and one for marking the order as payed.

```
$payer = $this->payerService->getPayer($payerUserId);
$this->orderService->payOrder($orderId, $payer);
```

In the `getPayer()` function you should make a call to the external library to know how many licences the payer have.

I hope this will be helpful, it is just based on what I understood from the questions and comments.